# How to enable HTTPS in Oracle cloud

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, https, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have instance running in oracle cloud and domain in Google Domains. I want to enable HTTPS, So I added A record in DNS  with HOST name www and valid ip address

[image]

I want to use the let's encrypt SSL for the domain. I followed this link
https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=ubuntufocal

But still HTTPS is not working.

Note: I have domain ending with ".dev".

Added A record in DNS

followed this link

https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=ubuntufocal

Answer (score 1):

From an OCI perspective, you must ensure that inbound 443/TCP is allowed for the instance in a security list for the subnet or a Network Security Group for the instance.

From the instance perspective:

- inbound iptables rules 443/TCP - check [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/enabling-network-traffic-to-ubuntu-images-in-oracle-cloud-infrastructure)
- enable SSL on apache: sudo a2enmod ssl

I don't know if certbot configures that in the instance. Did you check if the port 443 is up and listening?

Did certbot finish running fine or did you get errors?